# Serverless offline custom error from API gateway with Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Is there any way to return a custom error object and status code from API gateway? I am getting 200 status.

```
 var response = {
    status: 400,
    errors: [
       {
          code:   "226",
          message: "Password and password confirmation do not match."
        }
    ]
 }

context.done(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way I can change API Gatway. I can manage my API response to using s-templates.json to adding this code base.

```
ValidationError":{
  "selectionPattern": ".*ValidationError.*",
  "statusCode": "400",
  "responseParameters": {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-
    Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,Cache-Control,Token'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
  },
  "responseModels": {},
  "responseTemplates": {
    "application/json": "$input.path('$.errorMessage')"
  }
}
```

This way I return my response with 400 statusCode and a valid message.

```
module.exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  const validationError={
    statsCode:"ValidationError",
    section:"Login",
    validationType:"emailConfirmation",
    message:"Email is not confirmed",
    otherInfo:"Would you like to get the email again?",
    client:"web|ios|android"
  }
  context.done(null, response);
};
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to respond with an error, you have to use the success callback with an error response construct.

If you are using the context.fail() callback, AWS will assume that the Lambda technically failed and respond with the default mapping present in your API Gateway.

Sample error response:

```
'use strict';

module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 400,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      errors:[{
        code: "226",
        message:"Password confirmation do not match"
      }]
    }),
  };
  context.done(null, response);
};
```

Comment: Sorry I am not using context.fail. I am using context.done to send an error. I need to send status code also and valid msg to the client. Like when user trying to login without a valid password I need to send a message.

Comment: I updated the sample to a complete lambda. In your updated sample, the response is still wrongly set.

Comment: It returns status code 200. I need to send status code 400 with a valid message. when user trying to login without a valid password I want to send status code 400 and with a valid message.

Comment: Look this article you get some idea what's the issue I am getting. 

[link] (https://kennbrodhagen.net/2016/03/09/how-to-return-a-custom-error-object-and-status-code-from-api-gateway-with-lambda/)

Comment: This blog post uses AWS API Gateway directly with its own mapping, You on the other hand stated that you are using the serverless-framework, which would configure the Gateway and mapping for you. The sample I was giving is for a serverless-framework configuration. If you are doing the config and mapping by hand (as stated in the blog post), that is where you need to look for an error.

Comment: Do you know how to send status code 400 with a valid message? your provided solution return 200.

Comment: Again, if you are using the serverless-framework, the solution provided returns a http code 400. If you are using the solution from the blog post, your data is correct, but you need to adjust your API Gateway response mapping (as described in the blog post) and the callback function call. The blog post clearly describes why in this scenaria (with its custom mapping), a context.fail() invocation is neccessary. "One final note about the Regex phase. Regex matching only occurs if your Lambda function calls context.fail()."